# Running a python module in terminal through c (debian)

Tags: python, c

So I'm trying to run a python module through c code. It's a module which plays an animation. To run the animation in console I type (after navigating to its directory which is /home/pi/scrawler):

```
python3 -m scrawler.examples.animation
```

however, when I try putting this in my c code as:

```
system ("sudo /home/pi/scrawler")
system ("sudo python3 -m scrawler.examples.animation")
```

it gives me this error:
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for "scrawler.examples.animation" (ImportError : No module named 'scrawler')

How can I solve this error? 
Much thanks! :)

Comment: Did you mean `system("sudo cd /home/pi/scrawler")`.  Why not just invoke it like this `system ("sudo python3 -m /home/pi/scrawler/scrawler.examples.animation")`

Comment: Your first `system` command runs in a different process to the second, so it is a waste of time.  Use the full path name for the python script, or use `chdir()` in the C.

Comment: I have already tried that and it gave me the same importerror @cleblanc

Comment: Did you try `chdir()` in C?  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html

Comment: Maybe try `system("sudo /home/pi/scrawler;sudo python3 -m scrawler.examples.animation")`

Comment: I already trying everything on the same line, still gives me the same error, how would I use chdir() here? Sorry I've never programmed with c before :) @cdarke

Comment: @cleblanc also tried that, still not working :(

Comment: @sleepysloth try adding `#include <unistd.h>` and use `chdir("/home/pi/scrawler")` before calling `system("python3 -m scrawler.examples.animation");` as suggested by @cdarke

Comment: I tried that just now and it's giving me the same error, I have also tried doing    char *directory = "/home/pi/scrawler-master"; chdir(directory); and it still gives me the same error

Comment: Running animations with `sudo`? This does not look very secure…

Comment: Are you sure the module is where you say?  In the comment above you use `scrawler-master`, in your code you say `scrawler`.

Comment: When I run Python Modules from bash I have to change active directory to the upper directory. In your case this would be `chdir("/home/pi")`.

Comment: I had a typo in my chdir but didn't notice it until now, it works now thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change directory in your C program:

```
#include <limits.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int result;
    char curr_dir[PATH_MAX+1] = {0};

    // Get the current directory
    char * wd = getcwd(curr_dir, PATH_MAX);
    if ( wd == NULL ) {
         perror("Unable to getcwd");
         exit(1);
    }

    // Change to the required directory
    result = chdir("/home/pi/scrawler");
    if ( result == -1 ) {
         perror ("Unable to chdir");
         exit(1);
    }

    result = system ("sudo python3 -m scrawler.examples.animation");
    if ( result != 0 ) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Returned error %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(result));
         exit(1);
    }

    // Change back to the original directory
    result = chdir(curr_dir);
    if ( result == -1 ) {
         perror ("Unable to chdir back");
         exit(1);
    }

    // Any other code

    return 0;
}
```